# Parse JSON Data in Swift from API Call "Value of type 'Any?' has no subscripts"

Tags: json, swift, xcode, parsing

I am trying to parse some JSON data returned from an API call. The path I want to navigate is media > faces > tags. When I navigate to media it works, but when I add faces i receive the "Value of type 'Any?' has no subscripts" error.

I know this has been covered before on Stackoverflow but I can't seem to find out what is wrong. Any help is appreciated!

```
let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.mutableContainers) as? [String:Any];

//                        print(dictionary!["media"]) //this line works 

                        print(dictionary!["media"]["faces"]) // this line does not work
```

The API returned data looks something like this

```
Optional({
    checksum = 44efb3256385bfe62425c5fde195a3352e814ff6d900058e47a07b2cd7654252;
    duration = "00:00:00";
    faces =     (
                {
            angle = "1.2222";
            "appearance_id" = 0;
            "detection_score" = 1;
            duration = "00:00:00";
            "face_uuid" = "78338d20-9ced-11ea-b153-0cc47a6c4dbd";
            height = "74.31999999999999";
            "media_uuid" = "fec83ac3-de00-44f0-ad5b-e1e990a29a8c";
            "person_id" = "";
            points =             (
                                {
                    name = "basic eye left";
                    type = 512;
                    x = "85.16";
                    y = "86.62";
                },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the value returned from `dictionary!["media"]` as another `Dictionary` to be able to do this. Try this:

```swift
if let data = data,
    let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:.mutableContainers) as? [String: Any],
    let media = dictionary["media"] as? [String: Any] {
    print(media["faces"])
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use force unwraps anywhere though. Think about something like: `if let dictionary = try JSONSerialization... as? [String:Any] {  ... }` and for each level you descend in the JSON do it like `if let media = dictionary["media"] as? [String: Any] { ... } `

Comment: @mmika1000 Yes, you're right shouldn't use force unwraps. Also, You don't need the multiple `if let`s for that, I've updated my answer. Check and consider upvoting.